# Set if-condition for new line every 10th character

Tags: java, arrays, modulo

I'd like to enter a new line after the 10th array. My array is filled from 1-365 `(day[0]=1, day[1]=2, ..)`.

This is my code and i stuck at creating the `if-condition`:

```
int day[] = new int[365];

        for(int i=0; i<day.length; i++){
            day[i] = i+1;
            System.out.print(day[i]+" ");
            if((i % 10) == 0){
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

This should be my console output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
51 ...
```

What I'm getting:

```
1 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 
42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your condition to :

```
        if(((i+1) % 10) == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
```

You are printing `i+1`, so you want to add a line break when `i+1` is divisible by 10.

Comment: Thank you!! Worked! I'll add accept your answer soon as possible :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also skip using the array and print like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 365; ++i) {
        System.out.format("%3d ", i + 1);
        if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
 11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
 21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30 
 31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40 
 41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50 
 51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60 
 61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70 
 71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80 
 81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90 
 91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 
101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 
....
```

Comment: I can't because my teacher want that we do it like suggested above ;)

Comment: @8m47x haha, ok, no problem ;)

Comment: I'm going to learn java and this will be one of much other things that i have to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the array index starts at 0. So what you consider the 10th character is, to Java, the 9th (the first being the 0th).

Check `((i + 1) % 10)` instead.

Alternatively you could check the actual value of `day[i]`, since you've already set that to `i + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be your solution for example:
If you don't understand it, make it much more easier for your example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("This would be your solution:");
    int day[] = new int[365];
    for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
        day[i]=i+1;
        //System.out.print(day[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
        int j = day[i];
        System.out.print(j+" ");

        if(j%10==0){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 int day[] = new int[365];

    for(int i=1; i<day.length; i++){
        day[i-1] = i;
        System.out.print(day[i-1]+" ");
        if((i % 10) == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
        if(i==day.length-1){
            day[i] = i+1;
            System.out.print(day[i]+" ");
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 

21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 

31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 

41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
.......
```

Comment: This will result in 0-364, not 1-365.

Comment: @James 1-364 you mean, instead of 1-365. But you are right that the code is incorrect.

Comment: Oh yeah, 1-364 will be printed. Was just thinking of the contents of the array.

Comment: @Shree Now that you've edited it, it's still incorrect. `i <= day.length` will give you an IndexOutOfBoundsException once you reach index 365. @NielsBillen and @Eran answered correctly.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake.  I missed the boundary condition .I have fixed it now